# Scalable solution for converting an image sequence to video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, video-editing

We are developing a stop motion app for kids and schools.

So what we have is:

- A sequence of images and audio files (no overlapping audio, in v1. But there can be gaps between them)

What we need to do:

1. Combine the images to a video with a frame rate between 1-12 fps
2. Add multiple audio files at a given start times
3. encode with H265 to mp4 format

I would really like to avoid maintaining a VM or Azure batch jobs running ffmpeg jobs if possible.

Is there any good frameworks or third party APIs?
I have only found transloadit as the closes match but they don't have the option to add multiple audio files.

Any suggestions or experience in this area is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've mentionned FFmpeg in your tag and it is a tool that checks all the boxes.
For the first part of your project (making a video from images) you should check this [link](https://hamelot.io/visualization/using-ffmpeg-to-convert-a-set-of-images-into-a-video/). To sum up, you'll use this kind of command:

```
ffmpeg -r 12 -f image2 -i PATH_TO_FOLDER/frame%d.png PATH_TO_FOLDER/output.mp4
```

`-r 12` being your framerate, here 12. You control the output format with the file extension. To control the video codec check out this [link](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Main-options), you'll need to use the option `-c:v libx265`before the filename of your output.

With FFmpeg you add audio as you add video, with `-i` option followed by your filename. If you want to cut audio you should [seek](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking) in your audio with `-ss` `-t` two options good for that. If you want and audio to start at a certain point, check out `-itoffset`, you can find a lot of [examples](http://alien.slackbook.org/blog/fixing-audio-sync-with-ffmpeg/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The thing is that ffmpeg, means maintaing a VM or azure batch jobs, (as far as i know? haven't found any good third party services). As far as i found, it doens't match what i want, not out of the box at least. I can not add multiple audio files with space in between. When using offset, you can only apply one audio file, and remove any existing audio. I don't want to cut or seek in the audio at any point. Also, maybe I've done something wrong, but when using '-c:v libx265' my files got 10 times larger then by the default encoding (think it's H264?).

Comment: I don't know what infrastructure you want to deploy your app on but FFmpeg can run locally on a lot of machines. It can be CPU intensive (moreover with H265). For your audio problem I think you'd find a good method [there](https://superuser.com/questions/762886/ffmpeg-add-multiple-audio-files-to-video-at-specific-points). The size of your output file depends on the [encoder settings](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#toc-Codec-Options).